# Can I choose multiple layers in Photoshop in the same manner as selecting multiple objects in MS Word?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

Selecting multiple objects in MS Word is very easy. You just drag along the page and all the objects such as pictures are automatically selected. Is there the same way in Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select multiple layers by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> + click.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> + click selects additional layers individually, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click selects all layers in between and including your current one and the one you click on.

*For more info see: [Photoshop / Selecting, grouping, and linking layers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-78d2a.html)*

Answer (score 2):

No, not on the canvas. But if you want to select everything, simply select the top layer, hold shift and select the bottom layer in Layers panel. There is also an option in Select menu called "Select all layers" for this.

If you want to select layers directly on the canvas, turn on Auto-select (visible on the top right part of Photoshop when Move tool is used).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Just learnt this neat trick from http://www.elated.com/articles/selecting-layers-in-photoshop/

1. Use the Move tool
2. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (PC) or <kbd>cmd</kbd> (Mac)
3. Click on background layer or transparent area and drag the cursor
   over the layers you want to select. Only works if auto-select is disabled.

Any layer that falls within the marquee is going to be selected

Huge time saver.

Comment: wow that's new to me... Nice one!

Answer (score -2):

You can simply click layer by layer on the canvas while holding the shift key.

Or you can select the layers you need by selecting layer by layer by clicking on the layers along with the CTRL button from the layer window.

Comment: Can you please add an screenshoot to show what you mean?

Comment: ii tried to send a screen shot but cant figure out how to do is.

Comment: Edit your answer, find the graphic symbol  button, add the image (then you see something like `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`) and delete the `!` to deactivate it. One with more rep can activate it for you ...

Comment: first option  is  click on each layer one by one  while pressing the shift key...  ( SHIFT + CLICK ). then you can see  each layer will get in to one box and in the layer window one by the layers you want  will get selected..

Comment: or you can simply ctrl+ click on each layer in the layer window